# window.location.replace to a different domain getting blocked by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I would like to use window.location.replace to automatically redirect the page to another website, depending on the response from an ajax request.  So, something like this...

```
$.ajax({
  success: function( outtahere ) {
    if ( outtahere ) window.location.replace( "http://www.somewhereelse.com" );
  }
});
```

I'm finding that for some people, the redirect is getting blocked by a pop-up blocker.  This is the default behaviour in Safari, for example.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: This is not the default behavior on safari. I just checked executing a piece of code in safari's console and it worked fine for me. Can you try this in safari console by going to jquery's website (so that page includes jquery)?  
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=864beb72efe013691b703d9061367aa5&format=json', 
    method: 'GET'
}).done(function(){
    console.log('this is done');
    window.location.replace('http://m.yahoo.com');
});
console.log('end')

Comment: My mistake -- it's not the default behaviour.  But if the pop-up blocker in Safari is enabled, it does prevent the redirect, for me.

Comment: Why don't you use `window.location.href = 'http://google.com'`